# Users post questions in documentation

Tags: feature-request, documentation, asking-questions

In the last few days, I came across multiple proposed changes in the documentation, that were actually questions.

For example:

- [SQLite.swift Compiler Error](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/proposed/changes/90960?draftId=76661)
- [Swift Can't drag text field into toolbar](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/proposed/changes/91709?draftId=77262)

I rejected them with the reason "other" and explained, that the question should be asked in Q&A. Additionally, I added the link `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask`.

Especially larger tags like `Java Language` have lots of proposed changes like this.

- [taking input of ÿûÿû ÿûÿû'ÿýÿûÿý from telnet](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/proposed/changes/90282)
- [Missing Return statement error](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/proposed/changes/90400)
- [can i use java to deploy cloud?](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/proposed/changes/76151)
- [i need to sort and loop Ads](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/proposed/changes/74012)

It looks like the number of questions posted in documentation is increasing, so I think we should do something about that.

I have two solutions in mind:

1. An user should have at least one post in the tag, where he wants to make changes. I think everyone who has posted something in Q&A knows, that this is the correct place for questions.
2. Add "This is a question" as reason to reject changes in documentation. This would make it more comfortable to reject these changes, than explaining the reason in other. Additionally, this could show the author links to useful information for beginners like the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Comment: +1. I like option #2.

Comment: You should get accustomed to the fact that some kind of users put their question *everywhere*, including answers, Meta Stack Overflow, other people's questions, Meta Stack Exchange, etc ... As @Cerbrus, I'm supporting option #2.

Comment: I've seen this happen. Unfortunately, the user just tried again with the exact same content. People just don't read. I don't like the idea of limiting participation in docs to tag score; I want to be able to correct grammar or remove plagiarism in any tag. It might make more sense to just rate limit, particularly those with 1 rep or low rep.

Comment: @Laurel: Documentation isn't exactly fast-paced, any way. Personally, I'd prefer a low rep limit. Like 10, or even 50 rep, to contribute changes.

Comment: @Laurel "People just don't read." This is definitely true, and probably more so for non-natives of the language in question.

Comment: @Laurel Leave a comment with some bold text (justified after a second attempt IMO)